# Can we say a certain yes to having probability independence for some events?

Tags: probability, causality

Mathematically it is just a question of assumption of proof to say that $P(A|B)=P(A)$ if A is independent from B. *However*, in real life is it possible to assume $P(A|B)=P(A)$ instead of $P(A|B)=(1-\frac{1}{99!})P(A)$? Is there a strong argument for independence?

Another way to put is would be with a dependency graph. In this case, each node is an event and an edge represents some degree of dependency. What we would like to prove is that in this universe we have an non connected graph.

Comment: Might [stats.se] or [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: @KyleKanos I thought of Physics because I preferred to see the posture of the physical point of view. Mathematicians are too idealist!

Comment: IMO, statisticians would be well-suited for this question.

Comment: @KyleKanos Okay. Do you know how to migrate a question? Thanks for the help.